# How to restart same function after breaking out of it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble with the part below where it says (elif Q1 not in...). I want to break out of function3 but then come back to function3 again, but when i tried calling function3 within function3 it didn't work? All thanks to anybody who could help (:

```
score=0

def function1():
    global score
    if Q1 == "9" or Q1 == "c" or Q1 == "C":
        score=score+1
        print("Your current score is","",score)
    else:
        print("Your current score is","",score)

name=str(input("Please enter your name"))
print("Welcome",name.capitalize())


Q1=str(input("Q1) How many sheeps is there per person in New Zealand?\n(A) 3\n(B) 7\n(C) 9\n(D) 11"))

def function3():
    if Q1=="9" or Q1=="c" or Q1=="C":
        function1()
    elif Q1 not in ("A", "a", "B", "b", "C", "c", "D", "d", "3", "7", "9", "11"):
        print("Your awnser is invalid, please try again")
        while True:
            break
    else:
        print("Uh oh you got it wrong")
        function1()

function3()
```

Comment: well you can call function3() befire break sttm, but u need another logic to break the nested function calling otherwise it will go in infinite loop and end up stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

To terminate execution of a function, you can use `return` instead of `break`. The reason is that you can not `break` out of a function but you can `return` from it.

In your particular case, one can do the following:

```py
    elif Q1 not in ("A", "a", "B", "b", "C", "c", "D", "d", "3", "7", "9", "11"):
        print("Your awnser is invalid, please try again")
        return
```

Once you `return` from the function, you can call it again. In your case, simply call `function3` as shown below.

```py
function3()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do here, but Q1 input should be inside function3 if you want to call it again and accept a new answer. Also, pass Q1 to function1() instead of making Q1 a global variable.

```
def function1(Q1):
    global score
    if Q1 == "9" or Q1 == "c" or Q1 == "C":
        score=score+1
        print("Your current score is","",score)
    else:
        print("Your current score is","",score)


def function3():
    Q1=str(input("Q1) How many sheeps is there per person in New Zealand?\n(A) 3\n(B) 7\n(C) 9\n(D) 11"))

    if Q1=="9" or Q1=="c" or Q1=="C":
        function1(Q1)
        return()
    elif Q1 not in ("A", "a", "B", "b", "C", "c", "D", "d", "3", "7", "9", "11"):
        print("Your answer is invalid, please try again")
        while True:
            break
    else:
        print("Uh oh you got it wrong")
        function1(Q1)
        return()

    function3()

function3()
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me greatly to solve my problem.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please consider marking the answer as accepted or up-voting if it solved your problem. This would be beneficial for others when they review this question at a later point in time. Thanks!